# JMS Serializer perfomance issues with more than 10000 entries

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Currently I'm building a PHP command that can update my ElasticSearch indices.

But, a big thing I've noticed is that serializing entities when my array holds more than 10000 of them is taking way too much time. I thought it would be linear, but either 6 or 9k entities takes like a minute (not much difference between 6 or 9k), but when you go past 10k, it just slows down to the point of taking up to 10 minutes.

```php
...
                // we iterate on the documents previously requested to the sql database
                foreach($entities as $index_name => $entity_array) {
                    $underscoreClassName = $this->toUnderscore($index_name); // elasticsearch understands underscored names
                    $camelcaseClassName = $this->toCamelCase($index_name); // sql understands camelcase names

                    // we get the serialization groups for each index from the config file
                    $groups = $indexesInfos[$underscoreClassName]['types'][$underscoreClassName]['serializer']['groups']; 

                    foreach($entity_array as $entity) {
                        // each entity is serialized as a json array
                        $data = $this->serializer->serialize($entity, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($groups));
                        // each serialized entity as json is converted as an Elastica document
                        $documents[$index_name][] = new \Elastica\Document($entityToFind[$index_name][$entity->getId()], $data);
                    }
                }
...
```

There's a whole class around that but that's what is taking the most of the time.

I can get that serialiazing is a heavy operation and that it takes time, but why is there next to no difference between 6, 7, 8 or 9k, but when above 10k entities it juste takes a lot of time ?

PS : For reference, [I've opened an issue on github](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/762).

EDIT :

To explain what I'm trying to do more precisely, we have a SQL Database on a Symfony project, using Doctrine to link both, and we're using ElasticSearch (and bundles FOSElastica and Elastica) to index our data into ElasticSearch.

The thing is, while FOSElastica takes care of updating a data that is updated in the SQL database, it doesn't update every index that contains this data. (For example, if you have an author and two books he wrote, in ES you'll have the two books with the author in it, and the author. FOSElastica only update the author, not the informations about the author in the two books).

So, to take care of that, I'm doing a script that listens on every update done through Doctrine that get every ElasticSearch document related to the one updated, and update them too. This works but is way too long on my stress test with more than 10000 big documents to update.

EDIT :

To add more informations about what I tried, I have the same problem when using the "populate" command from FOSElastica. When it's 9k, everything is fine and smooth, and when it's 10k, it takes a really long time.

Currently I'm running test with reducing the size of my array in my script and resetting it, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should check memory comsumption: You are building a big array with a lot objects listed in it.

You have either 2 solutions: Use a Generator to avoid building that array, OR try to push your documents every "x" iterations and reset your array.

I hope this gave you an idea on how to handle this kind of migrations.

By the way, I almost forgot to tell you to avoid using ORM/ODM repositories to retrieve data (in migration scripts). The problem is that they're gonna use objects and hydrate them, and honestly in huge migration scripts, you'll just wait forever for nothing. If possible, just use Database object, which will probably be sufficient for what you wanna do.

Comment: This makes sense, I guessed there was something about that. I should just test that and come back here.

Comment: By the way: Using an ORM/ODM in a migration script is a terrible idea. If you are using doctrine migrations bundle, just use the Database connection object to retrieve records in your database in their "array" style. Hydration and object creation through ODM are really not meant to be used in scripts of this size.

Comment: I don't think it can be called a "migration script", but I didn't explained what it was at all tbf, so I'll edit my post and try to explain what I'm trying to do exactly

Comment: Hi, just a question: did you remove elasticsearch autocommit ? We had almost same issues in one of the projects i worked on, and it really helped us a lot improving our performances. And by the way, try to profile your code using blackfire, you'll see where IS your bottleneck for sure with that. Try that first if possible. It's really Quick to setup then use, even in CLI mode.

Comment: Hello, well I didn't removed that, what do you mean by ElasticSearch autocommit ? I can't seem to find anything about it, would you have a link to the doc ?
Good call about Blackfire, I didn't know about it, thanks, this seems like a really neat tool

Comment: Hi, sorry the real word for that in elasticsearch is "refresh": it means on everypush, your index will be refreshed to take into account new documents. During bulk opérations, this might be problematic. The Idea is to disable that behaviour during bulk operations then put it back once you finished. You Can check that here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the way my algorithm works, and get first all the ids that needs to be updated, then get them from the database by batch of 500-1000 (I'm running tests).

```php
                    /*
                    * to avoid creating arrays with too much objects, we loop on the ids and split them by DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE
                    * this way we get them by packs of DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE and add them by the same amount
                    */ 
                    for ($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($idsToRequest) ; $i++) {
                        $currentSetOfIds[] = $idsToRequest[$i]; 

                        // every time we have DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE ids or if it's the end of the loop we update the documents
                        if ($i % self::DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE == 0 || $i == sizeof($idsToRequest)-1) {
                            if ($currentSetOfIds) {

                                // retrieves from the database a batch of entities
                                $entities = $thatRepo->findBy(array('id' => $currentSetOfIds)); 

                                // serialize and create documents with the entities we got earlier
                                foreach($entities as $entity) {
                                    $data = $this->serializer->serialize($entity, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($groups));
                                    $documents[] = new \Elastica\Document($entityToFind[$indexName][$entity->getId()], $data);
                                }

                                // update all the documents serialized
                                $elasticaType->updateDocuments($documents);

                                // reset of arrays
                                $currentSetOfIds = [];
                                $documents = [];
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I'm updating them by the same amount, but it still doesn't improve the performance on the serialization method. I don't really understand how it can be this different to the serializer that I have 9k or 10k entities when it never knows that...